# HTML text unselectable but with a twich ! UNDELETABLE

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, google-chrome-extension, safari-extension

I know about **-moz-user-select**: none; **-webkit-user-select**: none; **-khtml-user-select**: none; and it works fine in the code i have .

But i want to make my div unselectable by **Ctrl+A also**, which the above directives don't seem to have an effect on.

How can i disable this selection in Firefox for example? I want to be able to prevent selection with Ctrl+A so that the Del key won't delete the text. I want to make the text un-deletable.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable to the Ctrl-A keypress as follows but this won't do the whole job, since the browser's context and Edit menus will still have "Select All" options.

```
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 65) {
        return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: Yeah, but i need only my div to remain unselected. The rest of the text inside the iframe should be in the normal workflow. Thanks , anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Using this with the CSS above:

```
::selection {
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
        }
::-moz-selection {
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```

Won't necessarily make it unselectable, but the user won't be able to see what's being selected. ;)

Edit: In response to your comment below, take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/Shaz/fM8p4/

Comment: Thanks but i think this is not what i want ! I want to be able to prevent selection with Ctrl+A so that the Del key won't delete the text.

Comment: @alex Take a look at the link I posted above.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The problem is that my div is '#test' and i want to prevent the deletion of the whole div structure, not elements within it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you're trying to do; are you looking for something like this:

```
<div contenteditable="true">
  This part is editable.
  <div contenteditable="false">
    This part is not editable or deletable.
  </div>
  This part is editable again.
<div>
```